# How to use Strategy and others for email sending

Tags: c#, email, design-patterns

I want to use various email providers like GMail, mailgun, mailchimp etc
   and create a library to use. Those providers allow to send emails using SMTP, HTTP Post,
   REST based APIs etc. Currently I have defined the following interfaces

```
interface IEmailSendStrategy // how to send email like SMTP , REST , HTTP Post etc ??
{
   void Send(IEmailSender sender);
}
interface IEmailSender      // provider like GMail , mailchimp, mailgun
{
    void SendEmail(ISendStrategy strategy, System.Net.Mail.Message message)
}
```

and some classes implementing these interfaces

```
class SMTPStrategy : IEmailSendStrategy
{
    void Send(IEmailSender sender){ // code to send }
}
class GMailSender : IEmailSender
{
    void SendMail(ISendStrategy strategy, System.net.Mail.Message message){ // code }
}
```

Now my question is

1) Is this a good approach to develop a EmailLib, any pitfalls or wrong design here ?

2) How can I put more data into these classes in a DesignPattern-Way

( like the usernames, pwds, ports, SSL or not, AUthentication for REST etc etc...

I thought of IData and use concrete classes for those IData ( like SMTPData, etc.. )

but each one may have its own type of SMTPData ( gmail needs SSL, different port, may use

some MD5 authentication etc, etc )

3) Any suggestions are welcome to make this a robust library ( I will put it as open source

later on )

Thanx

Comment: You can use Provider mechanism to design you sender. Create a class EmailProviderBase from ProviderBase then create the inherited classes that imlement concrete functionality. Then create an EmailServicedClass which will load an appropriate provider from .config or directly from the code.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I don't necessarily see the point in splitting out ISendStrategy and IEmailSender. I'd suggest you consider how you're going to use the code. Having briefly thought about it, I would suggest that one interface should be sufficent. Perhaps something like this...

```
public interface IEmailService {
    public Send(IAuthenticationDetails details, IMessage message)
}

public class GMail : IEmailService {
    public GMaily() { //... }
    public Send(IAuthentication details, IMessage message) {
        //...
    }
}

public class AnotherClasss {
    public void AMethodToSendEmail(...) {    
       // use factory or container to get instance of strategy
       strategy.Send(details, message)
    }
}
```

Comment: So say I want to do two things
Send an Email using MailGun and their SMTP settings
Send an Email using MailGUn with their REST API
Send an Email using gmail and smtp settings

How can it be using these interfaces and say classes ( roughly )
Thanx